# How to group values from a table if they're close?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Let's say I define 10 as being a close enough difference between two values, what I want is the average of all the values that are close enough to each other (or in other words, grouped by their closeness). So, if I have a table with the following values:

```
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     1 |
|     2 |
|     4 |
|     2 |
|     1 |
|     4 |
|     3 |
|    22 |
|    23 |
|    24 |
|    22 |
|    20 |
|    19 |
|    89 |
|    88 |
|    86 |
+-------+
```

I want a query that would output the following result:

```
+---------+
| 2.2500  |
| 21.6667 |
| 87.6667 |
+---------+
```

Where 2.2500 would be produced as the average of all the values ranging from 1 to 4 since they're for 10 or less away from each other. In the same way, 21.6667 would be the average of all the values ranging from 19 to 24, and 87.6667 would be the average of all the values ranging from 86 to 89.

Where my specified difference of what is currently 10, would have to be variable.

Comment: I suspect your last line, "Where my specified difference of what is currently 10, would have to be variable." makes this problem significantly harder for you.  Could you elaborate on what you mean by this?  What determines acceptably close, for instance?

Comment: How would you group the table that consists of all consecutive integers from 1 to 100?

Comment: Also the question I wondered was if one number could be used in more than one calculation

Comment: @dimo414 Well the thing is that 10 may not be the right value for this "close enough" parameter, so what I meant was that i didn't want it to be divided by 10 and looking at the remaining, I wanted to be able to change 10 to let's say 99, in which case i would get just one row as a result in my example.

Comment: @PM77-1 By their belonging, so to say. For example all "small" numbers, all "middle" numbers, and all "large" numbers.. however arguable the definition of those terms may be.

Comment: @user1389596 No, they shouldn't

Comment: @3Nex so the value to group by is arbitrary (i.e. has no significance to the algorithm) but not variable (i.e. different groups could be grouped by different amounts), correct?

Comment: @dimo414 Correct, good point, sorry for expressing myself wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't so bad.  You want to implement the `lag()` function in MySQL to determine if a value is the start of a new set of rows.  Then you want a cumulative sum of this value to identify a group.

The code looks painful, because in MySQL you need to do this with correlated subqueries and join/aggregation rather than with ANSI standard functions, but this is what it looks like:

```
select min(value) as value_min, max(value) as value_max, avg(value) as value_avg
from (select t.value, count(*) as GroupId
      from table t join
           (select value
            from (select value,
                         (select max(value)
                          from table t2
                          where t2.value < t.value
                         ) as prevValue
                  from table t
                 ) t
            where value - prevvalue < 10
           ) GroupStarts
           on t.value >= GroupStarts.value
      group by t.value
     ) t
group by GroupId;
```

The subquery `GroupStarts` is finding the break points, that is, the set of values that differ by 10 or more from the previous value.    The next level uses join/aggregation to count the number of such break points before any given value.  The outermost query then aggregation using this `GroupId`.

Answer (score 0):

Create another column with a hash value for the field.  This field will be used to test for equality.  For example with strings you may store a soundex.  For numbers you may store the closest multiple of ten

Otherwise doing a calculation will be much slower.  You could also cross join the table to itself and group where the difference of the  two fields < 10

Comment: If, for example, i only had 9 and 11 in the table, this approach would group them in different groups. This is not acceptable, as i need 9 and 11 to be in the same group because they are for less than 10 apart from each other.

Comment: Though you can update all hash values after each insert or update.  Or update the hash before running the report.  If you read data more often than write, it will be faster than a join.

Answer (score 0):

I like the other user's suggestion to create a hash column.  Joining to yourself has an exponential effect, and should be avoided.

One other possibility is to use /, for example select avg(val), val/10 from myTable group by val/10 would have a value of group that is 0 for 0-9, 1 for 10-19, etc.

At least, it works in SQL Server that way

Comment: Both are good aproaches, but there's one thing wrong. If my group value would be the result of dividing by 10, then numbers 9 and 11 would end up in different groups, which they shouldn't (as per my example with 19 and all the 20's) because they are for less than 10 apart from each other.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I would export to an array the whole result.

Afterwards, use a function

```
function show(elements_to_agroup=4)
{
for (i = 0; i < count(array) ; i++)
{
sum = 0;    

if (i % elements_to_agroup)
    { 
    sum = sum / elements_to_agroup; 
    return sum;
    }    
else
    {
    sum =+ array[i];
    }
}
}
```